# Why does my computer freeze when I adjust the brightness?

Tags: 12.04, brightness

As the title says, in 12.04, when I hold <kbd>FN</kbd> and press the up and down arrow keys to adjust my screen brightness, the screen starts to flicker, and the OS freezes. I have to hold the power button to force it to shut down, and start it back up. I can't seem to adjust the brightness.

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug on my Samsung laptop.  The trick that fixed everything for me was to add a boot parameter to grub during loading.  You can test to see if it works first by rebooting the machine and pressing `e` when the boot menu appears.  Then edit the kernel line to add `acpi_osi=` after the `quiet splash` part. Then execute grub (I forget the exact key combo, cntl-x or something). This basically tells the kernel to "lie" to the bios that you're not running Linux.

If it works, you can make it permanent by editing `/etc/default/grub` to add it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter. Update grub by running `sudo update-grub`